# How to use fabric8 java api with AWS EKS

Tags: amazon-iam, fabric8, amazon-eks

I want to use java fabric api to access AWS EKS and manage it. The calling code using java fabric api should be able to authenticate with AWS IAM.
Something like below, but should be able to access AWS APIs

```
 io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.Config k8sConfig = new ConfigBuilder()
                .withApiVersion(V1)
                .withClientCertData(clusterCert.cert)
                .withTrustCerts(true)
                .withCaCertData(clusterCert.cert)
                .withClientKeyData(clusterCert.key)
                .withMasterUrl(cluster.apiUrl)
                .build();
```

Any suggestion should be highly appreciated.